# HoloLens 2 "emulator unable to verify that the virtual machine is running. access is denied" error

Tags: visual-studio-2022, hololens

I have a freshly installed Windows 11 22H2 OS (all updates installed), with a freshly installed Visual Studio 2022 (all updates installed), on my Surface Book 2. My local user is running in the local Administrators group and in the Hyper-V group. The machine isn't attached to a domain. I have started Visual Studio post-install, as I know that is sometimes necessary for adjacent tooling to work. The OS and VS2022 are all logged into my Microsoft account.

I install the HoloLens 2 Emulator 10.0.20348.1522 and try to run it. I got a few different error dialogs that happen after a bunch of CPU and I/O activity observed in Task Manager:

"`emulator unable to verify that the virtual machine is running. access is denied.`"

and

"`the emulator is unable to create a differencing disk`"

After an unsuccessful launch with those errors, I then get "disk image is in use" until I reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this error message, this is an issue under review to be addressed in a future update to the Windows 11 22H2 operating system.

To resolve the error for now, running the emulator as an administrator will allow this to be unblocked.  If you are running the emulator from Visual Studio, running Visual studio as administrator will resolve this issue too.  Specifically, launch from the shell as an administrator:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks! Hopefully the automated test suite for the installer/emulator gets expanded so this doesn’t regress again in the future — I found message boards with numerous  people complaining about similar things in 2017.

Comment: Great to hear it worked for you too.  For this one, it is an OS change that is needed to Windows 11 22H2.  So, the emulator is not the core issue for this one.  Hopefully, an OS update will be coming in new year to not have to manually run as administrator to workaround the error.

Comment: Hi @Nathan-MSFT I open VS2022 Comm 17.4.3 right-click VS to open as admin, double click on the sln but says unloaded. However if I open the sln directly (not open VS as admin first) it opens correctly and lets me build for emulator (though then emulator gives error as per above post). I can't therefore build for emulator. There is no option to set as start project either. Can you please share screenshots what needs to be done to run on emulator? Im on Win 11 pro v10.0.22621, HoloLens 2 Emulator (10.0.20348.1531). Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sergio, if reading this correctly, just need to run VS2022 as admin and then, do file open to load the solution versus trying to launch from shell.  We are getting closer to an update that will remove the running admin workaround.  Will update in new year when getting closer on that topic